# How to Auto-Size a Background for 3D text in ARKit

Tags: swift, arkit, scntext

I am trying to generate a background that automatically conforms to the size of the 3D that my program generates using ARKit. Is their a way to do that using swift/xCode or is there a way to calculate what size the background would have to be?

For example:
text1 = "abc"

would only need a small background, where as:
text2 = "abcdefg \n 1234567 \n testing123"

would need a bigger background, and the text and background would also vary with the size of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into `boundingBox`

```
let text = SCNText(string: "123", extrusionDepth: 0.1)
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)

let (min, max) = textNode.boundingBox
print("width :",max.x - min.x,"height :",max.y - min.y,"depth :",max.z - min.z)
```